# div not centered vertically on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile, vertical-alignment

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help. I have a div containing an animation, that containing div is centered vertically to the page using simple JS. It works perfectly on desktops, but for some reason on mobile devices it animates partially below the screen, then snaps up into it's correct position after.

I am fairly new to JS so I figure that is where the problem lies. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

html:

```
<div id="center-height">
  <div id="animation-container">
     <div class="svg-container center" id="cocktail-container">
      <svg class="svg-element" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 216 460" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
        <a xlink:href="http://getriot.com/work.php">
        <path id="cocktail" stroke="#c59949" stroke-width="2.5" fill="#c59948" fill-opacity="0" d="M42.54,5.33c31.15,44.48,9.79,46.43,12.01,58.27c6.68,35.78,39.77,16.09,44.3,50.9c0.53,8.55-17.69,1.14-29.44-11.31c-1.18,26.57,12.31,37.77,14.74,39.01c9.65,4.9,29.03-0.27,29.34,28.13
        c4.57,16.8,30.31-5.01,32.47,1.79c1.5,6.01-2.35,6.84-5.09,19.96c-0.7,9.81,4.34,15.69,12.5,19.12
        c-6.71,11.63-15.11,26.2-16.41,28.45c-4.12,7.13-18.44,11.34-24.02,12.66c-12.25,2.89-23.31,10.62-30.1,22.39l-0.13-0.07
        c0,0-72.44,125.59-76.51,132.65c7.11,26.47,58.06,53.76,82.04,47.32c3.19-5.52,76.51-132.65,76.51-132.65l-0.05-0.03
        c6.79-11.76,7.95-25.23,4.31-37.28c-1.67-5.53-5.27-20.03-1.15-27.17c1.06-1.83,17.46-30.28,23.1-40.05
        c16.77-2.57,32.52-42.78,6.27-51.3c-9.39-2.26-5.62,16.56-23.17,13.77c6.18-10.6,12.26-19.79,12.02-30.06
        c-0.76-10.7-7.04-11.03-16.96-9.88c15.88-37.74-14.86-32.48-13.73-55.13c-13.94,8.29-5.51,32.7-12.76,29.02
        c-14.22-7.87-7.21-20.76-8.47-30.8c-0.58-4.63-2.43-20.58-34.97-35.74c2.7,4.73,8.25,30.08,2.87,29.5
        C89.1,75.59,88.6,65.63,86.79,58.91C86.31,47.62,70.43,24.26,42.54,5.33 M105.41,302.8c-10.89-1.97-26.02,10.8-20.82,34.33
        c4.68,13.26,12.81,9.4,15.76,29.63c1.78,12.16,17.48,12.41,22.63,7.18L81.8,445.33c-9.28,0.54-23.75-3.88-37.07-11.57
        c-13.09-7.55-23.33-17.19-27.35-25.52c0,0,49.66-85.79,53.78-92.93C76.74,305.62,91.8,290.69,105.41,302.8 M75.46,413.65
        c-4.78-2.76-10.89-1.12-13.66,3.66c-2.76,4.78-1.12,10.9,3.67,13.66c4.78,2.77,10.9,1.12,13.66-3.66
        C81.89,422.53,80.26,416.42,75.46,413.65 M78.39,365.17c-2.51-1.45-5.72-0.59-7.16,1.92c-1.45,2.51-0.58,5.72,1.92,7.16
        c2.51,1.45,5.72,0.59,7.17-1.92C81.75,369.83,80.9,366.61,78.39,365.17 M55.8,376.96c-3.34-1.93-7.6-0.78-9.52,2.55
        c-1.93,3.33-0.78,7.59,2.56,9.51c3.33,1.92,7.6,0.78,9.51-2.56C60.27,383.14,59.12,378.88,55.8,376.96"/>
        </a>
      </svg>
    </div>        
    <h1 id="home-title">title<br /><span class="home-icons"><i id="i-1" class="fa fa-object-ungroup"></i><i id="i-2" class="fa fa-code"></i><i id="i-3" class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></span></h1>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
#animation-container {
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 78%;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
top: 45%;
-moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
transform: translateY(-50%);}
```

JS:

```
<script>
  $(document).foundation();
  var windowHeight = $(window).height();
  var animationHeight = $('#animation-container').height();      
  $('#center-height').css("height", windowHeight + 'px');
</script>
```

If you want see it in action you can visit [GetRiot.com](http://getriot.com). Again, it works on desktop, but has that strange glitch on mobile.

Comment: The issue is that the height of the overall container extends below the actual screen. So while the animation is being centered in the container, it looks like it's not centered because the container is taller than the screen.

Comment: I agree. I just can't figure out why it is extending past the screen on mobile, and only for a second before the proper positioning kicks in. But, on desktop it works without a problem.